# In this program, why is the timing for the if statement always the same as the preceding function?

Tags: python, performance, time

I'm trying to learn to do more efficient coding. Problem is, my degree literally didn't bring up the topic; our professor seriously encouraged us to make convoluted spaghetti code so that an employer would have to re-hire us if they wanted the code we made for them re-worked.

Given the misinformation on the internet, I decided the be avenue to find this out would be to test out the timing of various functions myself. This thing's been having a number of issues.

For instance, the average time each function takes various widely no matter how many tries I have it average together. This may or may not be related to my latest problem. For some reason, it tells me an if statement always takes the same execution time as the preceding function completely regardless of what it is. At first, this was a print statement. I decided it shouldn't be too surprising that the execution of an if-statement that doesn't execute its line should be compatible to any other single command. Besides, the same thing happened when I had it test an increment statement; all three always output the same result. The only time the if-statement was different when I did have the if statement fire its then statement. Its hard to say how reliable it is given the variance in the print command, but the results for an if statement clearly aren't just double the same print statement on its own.

However, I then added two functions to see how a for-loop compared to simply copying a line 10 times. It claims a for-loop is better than having 10 print lines. However, the execution time is well in excess of a single print statement, and the if-statement is now returning the same value as the 10 print lines!

What is happening here? Is my program actually generating real results? Have I run into some sort of glitch? How can I possibly find out how to make efficient code if I have no way to find out what constitutes efficient code? I'm trying to compare different statements so I can answer things like 'would using an if statement here actually be more efficient than not?' What is happening with this program to generate these results?

```
import time

avg=0

tries=100

true=True
false=False

for i in range(tries):
    t0=time.monotonic_ns()
    print("Test string")
    t1=time.monotonic_ns()
    avg+=t1
    avg-=t0

print("Print Command:",avg/tries/1000000)

for i in range(tries):
    x=0
    t0=time.monotonic_ns()
    x+=1
    t1=time.monotonic_ns()
    avg+=t1
    avg-=t0

print("Increment Int:",avg/tries/1000000)

for i in range(tries):
    t0=time.monotonic_ns()
    for i in range(10):
        print(true)
    t1=time.monotonic_ns()
    avg+=t1
    avg-=t0

print("For Loop 10:",avg/tries/1000000)

for i in range(tries):
    t0=time.monotonic_ns()
    print(true)
    print(true)
    print(true)
    print(true)
    print(true)
    print(true)
    print(true)
    print(true)
    print(true)
    print(true)
    t1=time.monotonic_ns()
    avg+=t1
    avg-=t0

print("10 Commands:",avg/tries/1000000)



for i in range(tries):
    t0=time.monotonic_ns()
    if false:
        print("Test string")
    t1=time.monotonic_ns()
    avg+=t1
    avg-=t0

print("If Statement:",avg/tries/1000000)
```

Comment: You need to reset `avg = 0` before each for loop.

Comment: Is that seriously what I did wrong? I feel like an idiot now... That said, I was thinking of giving them all they're own avg variable so they would all be printed at the bottom. Guess that would also fix the issue?

Comment: Yes, that would also work.

Comment: A word of advice, if you're really timing those statements you're doing premature optimization. There's no meaning to the kind of optimization you're trying to do there.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying. What I'm trying to do is collect data so I can chose the best way to optimize things. For instance, let's say you had a chain of 10 functions, and one function could call any number of them. Would it be better to use a line of if-statements, or just run all of them but set it up so inputs of 0 always output 0? I figured the only way to find out for myself would be to just see how fast an if statement is executed compared to various other functions.

Comment: "_how fast an if statement is executed compared to various other functions_" As I mentioned this kind of timing data is useless. When you have a need of conditional branching you'd be using an "if" statement in some form or the other. If you're timing just this to figure out how long an "if" statement takes to execute and not thinking about the content of the if-statement, etc. your timing is useless. If you're really worried about your program's speed I'd say you should start off with optimizing the time complexity instead of trying to figure out micro-optimizations like this.

Comment: I know the execution of each line is going to depend on how elaborate it is. For instance, I was thinking of testing different string lengths to see if it made a difference and if it did, how much. An if statement is probably a good idea for a large block of code that rarely executes, but what about a single line? I'm looking for the most rudimentary data so I could determine other things with it. I did list an example that I wanted an answer to. Are always-executing lines better or worse than a line of if-statements (as in no elif-statements).

Comment: First of all, any timings with I/O operations like print is pointless. They are inherently very slow and your program will be bottlenecked purely by amount of print statements you do. 2nd, testing fundamental building blocks, especially in a language with big overhead by default is kinda irrelevant. You can't generalize things like "Are always-executing lines better or worse than a line of if-statements?". You NEED to use both for a functioning program, and without a specific example, there's no way to say for sure.

Comment: With language like Python such structural micro-optimisations are also gonna have minimal impact compared to actual Big-O time complexity of your algorithms which is the first thing you should target when trying to optimise a program. And as someone already mentioned, [premature optimization is the root of all evil](https://ubiquity.acm.org/article.cfm?id=1513451#:~:text=Trying%20to%20do%20the%20optimization,best%20practice%20among%20software%20engineers.)

Comment: What I'm doing is NOT pre-optimization. If I was to try and optimize a program, I would literally have no clue how to do it. What types of blocks of code are more efficient than others? I can come up with alternate ways of doing things yes, but I have no way to predict if they're better or not. What, am I supposed to just use trial and error to figure out what I need to do? Just re-write the same program a different way over and over until I get a version that runs better? I'm trying to figure out how to do something I was never taught and have no way to find out.

Comment: @user8600  Optimization is a **huge** topic. To "know" what is better you need to understand memory addressing, compilation, call stack, Big-O complexity and a bunch of other quite complex topics. They all give you better insight into how you can optimize the program at different levels. For beginner in Python, I'd suggest 2 things to focus on - **data structures** (lists, dicts, sets etc.) and what each of them is good for, and **Big-O** complexity - that's the main thing you should have in mind when writing programs in terms of optimization, while not requiring a lot of programming knowledge

Answer (score -1):

Here's an easier way to read all averages:

```
import time

avg = 0

tries=1000

true=True
false=False

output = []

for i in range(tries):
    t0=time.monotonic_ns()
    print("Test string")
    t1=time.monotonic_ns()
    avg+=t1
    avg-=t0

output.append("Print Command: "+str(avg/tries/1000000))

for i in range(tries):
    x=0
    t0=time.monotonic_ns()
    x+=1
    t1=time.monotonic_ns()
    avg+=t1
    avg-=t0

output.append("Increment Int: "+str(avg/tries/1000000))

for i in range(tries):
    t0=time.monotonic_ns()
    for i in range(10):
        print(true)
    t1=time.monotonic_ns()
    avg+=t1
    avg-=t0

output.append("For Loop 10: "+str(avg/tries/1000000))

for i in range(tries):
    t0=time.monotonic_ns()
    print(true)
    print(true)
    print(true)
    print(true)
    print(true)
    print(true)
    print(true)
    print(true)
    print(true)
    print(true)
    t1=time.monotonic_ns()
    avg+=t1
    avg-=t0

output.append("10 Commands: "+str(avg/tries/1000000))



for i in range(tries):
    t0=time.monotonic_ns()
    if false:
        print("Test string")
    t1=time.monotonic_ns()
    avg+=t1
    avg-=t0

output.append("If Statement: "+str(avg/tries/1000000))

print('\n'.join(output))
```

Since you're using prints in the loops it's better to store the main prints you care about in a list and then print them all together at the end.

I did not add @Anonymous12358 advice to reset avg so this is not an answer and so you can copy and paste to your question.

Also, you probably want to use [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) for this kind of testing.

Comment: Your link is to the Spanish version, despite the fact that your answer is in English.

Comment: fixed the link.

Comment: So... you've introduced a list to collect the incorrect averages that the OP was printing and then printing the incorrect averages anyway? If you don't consider this an answer (You state "_this is not an answer_") then why have you posted it as one?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Because I can't post the full code as a comment (1692 characters vs 600) and even if I could it would look like shit? As I said I posted this just so OP has an easier time reading all averages since he's testing with the print function, he can ignore this answer, he can update his OP so someone else might copy and paste test the code and provide another solution to Anonymous12358's, if he does I'll delete this since it'll be no longer relevant. If not, then this can stay here like every other irrelevant answer on SO.